# Is it logical to make two versions of an app, one for prod and one for dev?

Tags: support, apps

Let's say I'm working on an app on a local dev server, `localhost:1234` for example. Once I feel ready, I upload any changes to a GitHub repo and have those changes sync with an online website, for example `exampleapp.com`.

Since I'm using authentication in my app, I'm going to need to specify my OAuth domain. My app's not published yet, so I'm fine with changing the domain to `localhost` so that I can test the auth on my local servers. But when I deploy it to `exampleapp.com`, however, the auth will fail to work because the settings allow only `localhost`.

So I made a second, almost identical app. It does a pretty good job of saying, "Please don't authenticate with me unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing!" This would allow me to have my prod version set up for `exampleapp.com` while the local version is set up for `localhost`.

Both app client IDs and keys are going to be in public code repositories, and the code will look something like this:

```js
const inDev = (location.host === "localhost:1234");
const clientId = inDev ? 12345 : 23456;
const apiKey = inDev ? "thisIsMyApiKey123" : "tryThisInProdSite789";
```

- Was this the most reasonable decision?
- Was there something else I could have done instead of creating another app?

Comment: Is this in the context of using the Stack Exchange API? You don't seem to have any [app] posts here ...

Comment: @Glorfindel 1. Yes. 2. The app is still in dev, and I don't want to post it if putting two client IDs and keys in public code is a security issue or something. That's the question - is it safe/logical to put this in public code? If it isn't, what are the alternatives to doing so that *are* safe?